# Blue/Green deployments with AWS CDK for Lambda

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a CDK stack that deploys various lambdas, each lambda has 2 aliases (DEV-A, DEV-B). Currently the process updates both aliases to point to the recent version that was deployed. With the CDK (v1.140) is it possible to deploy the lambdas and have one alias point to the current version and the other point to the previous version?

The way I'm doing it now is deploying the stack and then following up with an action that updates the LIVE alias to point to the previous version. But I'd like to see if it's possible to do that within the CDK?

Comment: "...action that updates the LIVE alias" What are these "live alias" and how do you deploy them?

Answer (score 0):

Do not publish your lambda during deployment (simple configuration to turn off. The alias will continue pointing to the previous lambda version. After deployment, programmatically reassign the alias to the newly created lambda version after smoke tests, etc.